# passing data to a directive for ng-repeat inside of the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I keep bumping my head on angular when I want to have a directive that displays a list of things, but I want it to be generic enough to handle more than one type/shape of object. For simple example lets say I have

```
<select ng-options="person.id by person in people" ng-model="selectPerson">
  <option>
     {{person.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

(Keep in mind that this is a simple example and something this simple would probably not benefit from being a directive)

Now I want to turn it into a generic directive called cool-select
I might try and do something like this in my js

```
//directive coolselect.directive.js
angular.module('mycoolmodule',[]).directive('coolSelect',function(){
    return {
       restrict:'E',
       templateUrl:'js/coolselectdirective/_coolselect.html',//html from example above
       scope:{
             items:'=',
             displayProperty:'@',
             idProperty:'@',
             selectedItem:'='
       },
       link:function(scope,element){
        //do cool stuff in here
       }
   }
});
```

But then here is where I start to throw up a little in my mouth

```
//html template _coolselect.html
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item[scope.idProperty] by item in items">
  <option>      
     {{item[scope.displayProperty]}}
   </option>
</select>
```

To be perfectly honest I am not even sure this would work in angular. I have seen what ui-select does by using an outer scope. Maybe that is the way to go?
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/dist/select.js#L892

But then I think I would need to get fancy with transclude, like ui-select does.
Isn't there an easier way? Am I trying to make directives to generic? Is this not a problem other people are running into?

EDIT:
In the end it would be ideal for it to look like this.

```
<cool-select repeat="person.id by person in people" display-property="name"></cool-select>
```

Comment: You should use the directive as an element and you use it as a class? When you change the restrict E to C, you can use it as an class.

Comment: Sorry the class, is just to show that there are custom styles associated with this element.

Comment: I took out the class to make it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see demo below how to pass each object from array to directive in ng-repeater

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.people = [{
    name: "John"
  }, {
    name: "Ted"
  }]

});

app.directive('user', function() {

  return {

    restrict: 'EA',
    template: "<p>*name:{{user.name}}</p>",
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      console.log(scope.user);
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="person in people" user="person"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for, check the edit for what I kind of want to do.

Comment: Ultimately after thinking about it I think this is the best solution, and I would like people who have the same problem to see this solution. I think it is a reminder of how "properly" to compose elements of multiple directives.

Comment: I must one up this question as it helped me see how much of a dummy I am for not putting brackets around my scope data objects and not wondering why it didn't work... Kudos sir

Answer (score 0):

## There are a few things to note here:

1. By placing `ng-repeat` on the `select` you are repeating the `select`.
2. The `select` element has a special attribute for repeating options called [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).
3. You don't need to refer to the `scope` in the template, just its properties. In an **AngularJS** template `scope` is implied, in fact that's the purpose of `scope`, to be the ["scope"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scope) that you are accessing properties within.
4. You are not instantiating the `coolSelect` directive because you have restricted it to being used as an **element** but you are trying to use it as a **class**.
5. If you want to make a directive to simplify this process each time you want to repeat options or other components you *will* need to use syntax like `item[displayProperty]` in order to make it **generic**.

Comment: Yea sorry, I was just whipping up a quick example, so there are some errors in the code, I tried to clean it up to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to build the options yourself with displayProperty in options tag  ng-options can do more

```
<select
ng-model="myOption"
ng-options="value.id as value.label  for value in myOptions">
<option value="">nothing selected Text</option>
</select>
```

value.id is the value  stored in the  ngModel myOption
value.label is the displayed label

```
<option value="">nothing selected Text</option>
```

for having a nothing selected option if necessary